# How to authorise a SSO org in sfdx?

Tags: salesforcedx, single-sign-on

You can authorise an org in sfdx via this command

`sfdx force:auth:web:login -r https://customer1customdomain.lightning.force.com -a customer1`

When the org is SSO-enabled, I can only login by bypassing SSO by appending **?login** to the URL:

https://customer1customdomain.lightning.force.com?login

However, I can't seem to make it authenticate the sfdx connected app.

How do you authorise sfdx in a SSO-enabled org?

Comment: what happens? It works fine for me if I use the following url `https://domainname.my.salesforce.com`. It opens a browser up which authenticates with SSO and says "successfully authorized" in the terminal

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that lands here with the same question:

You can bypass SSO when you manually login by adding this parameter to the login URL https://`mycompany`.my.salesforce.com`/?login`

However, to authorize in VS Code or sfdx, use the URL `login`.salesforce.com

```
sfdx org login web -r https://login.salesforce.com -a mycompany.PROD
```

Sometimes adding lightning login helps

Comment: For orgs that enforce login through the company's subdomain, the login or test generic subdomains do not work. In those cases, prefer to use the company domain instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the instance URL in your auth call:

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias my-hub-org --instanceurl <your domain here>
```

You may also be able to configure a connected app to handle the additional auth requirements as seen here: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth_connected_app.htm

and referenced here: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth_web_flow.htm

Answer (score -3):

This worked for me for Connecting SF org and i have SSO enabled on SF login.

If you want to connect to a custom domain org, you can use the URL `https://<yourdomain>`.my.salesforce.com, where `<yourdomain>` is the name of your custom domain.

Comment: Is this distinct from the 2 existing answers, or is it a "this existing answer worked for me"? If it's the latter, then you should delete this and upvote the answer you thought was helpful. If it is supposed to be a distinct answer, then you need to [edit] your answer so that the stuff you have inside of the angle brackets gets rendered as text (the site interprets it as html and prevents it from being displayed for security reasons).